# What things should I keep in mind before split toning an image?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing, split-tone

Split toning creates a nicer looks to even boring images. But only if it's done correctly. I do split toning and out of colors. I don't know what colors to use. In how much quantity. I don't even know which colors would suit on which photos.

What regulations do you follow when editing an image? What rules do you follow? Please share your experiences. I hope you understand.

Comment: Just my opinion, but split toning a boring image just makes a boring split tone image.

Comment: Trying? Comparing? Experience?

Comment: I never did split toning, or I would say never practice split toning on my image. As a hobbyiest photographer I would like to know more about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Keep the saturation subtle.  Adding too much color to a black and white image draws too much attention away from the actual image.  The color should not draw attention to itself.
2. Contrasting colors generally look nice together.  A common trick is using complimentary colors which are 180 degrees from each other on the color wheel.  The way to achieve this with a hue slider is to look at the number associated with the first hue you have chosen.  Subtract or add 180.  Use this new number for the other hue.
3. Keep in mind the historical use of toning.  Sepia (brown) is associated with "old" photos in many people's minds.  If you use it, it may cause many viewers to make this association (whether you intended it or not)
4. I would echo the opinion stated by others here, and make it a bit more general - No computer manipulation (split toning included) will make a great final image from a poor original image.

Answer (score 1):

Split Toning can be helpful if it is used marginal in my opinion but I don't use it that much. It can also help to get surreal pictures but remember it cannot rescue a bad/boring image.

To get a good starting point how to use it and to get a good base I would recommend you to look some Tutorial Videos [like this one](https://youtu.be/JreWiWRuJ7s) from Anthony Morganti on Youtube. He covers this very well.